# Inserting data to a database table using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i am in a bit of a jam, i connected my database and coded everything  way i think im supposed to but  i enter my data in my app it doesnt show up in my table,here is my code for my database

try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

```
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gateaccesscontrol?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","root");
       String Sql = "insert into visitors values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
       PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
       pstmt.setString(2,Datetxt.getText());
       pstmt.setString(3,Timetxt.getText());
       pstmt.setString(4, Nametxt.getText());
       pstmt.setString(5, Comptxt.getText());
       pstmt.setString(1,Regtxt.getText());
       pstmt.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(Teltxt.getText()));
       pstmt.setString(7, Reasontxt.getText());
       pstmt.setString(8,Persontxt.getText());
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"insertion successful");
       conn.close();


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: try pstmt.executeUpdate();  after last placeholder is set

Comment: You are a life saver!!!!